# ¿Cómo hacer un menú vertical en genexus?

Tags: html, css, genexus

Alguien me puede ayudar este menú se crearía desde las masterPague mas que nada quiero saber si es posible en base a las opciones que te da genexus o tengo que agregar html y css externos para poder llegar a este resultado.

saludos
gracias

Comment: Se puede hacer. Seria bueno ver una referencia de que es especificamente lo que queres lograr para entrar en detalles, pero en principio se puede hacer un menu vertical para web.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En el marketplace tenés un control para tener un menú con la posibilidad de anidar submenús.
Te permite desplegarlo tanto horizontal como vertical.

[Smooth Navigational Menu](https://marketplace.genexus.com/product.aspx?smoothnavigationalmenu,en)

La documentación del mismo está muy clara y es muy fácil de usar.